# How to stop support of old iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6

As I know such situation is ok, when you just stop making supporting of old iOS versions for your application. The question is how this changes should be implemented on my project. I mean at iTunes connect for example. At Xcode as I understand it's enough just to change deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload your new app to iTunes Connect, it'll use the iOS version specified in your deployment target. You don't need to specify it anywhere else.